# Is it valid to use val in where condition?

Tags: mysql

My query is

```
SELECT count(crm_clients.client_id) as count, (((sum(expectd_rev)/1000) +((COALESCE((sum(COALESCE(client_rating,0))/count(crm_client_assign.client_id)),0)*100)/5))/392.10000000)*100 as val
FROM (`crm_clients`)
JOIN `crm_project_assign` ON `crm_clients`.`client_id` = `crm_project_assign`.`client_id`
JOIN `crm_projects` ON `crm_project_assign`.`project_id` = `crm_projects`.`project_id`
LEFT JOIN `crm_client_assign` ON `crm_clients`.`client_id` = `crm_client_assign`.`client_id`
WHERE `ctype` =  2 and crm_clients.client_id in (select client_id from crm_project_assign)

group by crm_clients.client_id
order by val desc
```

is it possible to use val in where condition?any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not allowable for two reasons.  The first is that you can't use column aliases in the `where` clause.  The more important reason (in my opinion) is that `val` is composed of aggregation functions.  You cannot use aggregation functions in the `where` clause.

The solution is simple:  use a `having` clause.  This goes after the `group by` and you can just do:

```
having val > 10
```

or whatever you would like.

Answer (score 1):

#### No, you can't use that alias name in the `where` condition.

> It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.

You need to write that all again in the `where` condition.

Comment: when i directly use (((sum(expectd_rev)/1000) +((COALESCE((sum(COALESCE(client_rating,0))/count(crm_client_assign.client_id)),0)*100)/5))/392.10000000)*100 i got an error invalid group function

Comment: Not sure for what result you are looking for. But you can't use aggregate functions like that. Instead try `group by crm_clients.client_id having val = ? order by val desc`

Comment: i want the where condition is val>0 and val <20